# jQuery if checkbox is checked to toggle classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am needed to change my jQuery code up. Instead of the label toggling the class and showing the icon I need it to where if the checkbox is checked to show to toggle those classes. I have tried `prop` and `is` but I couldn't get them to work properly. The reason for the change is I want to preload data into the form and if it's going to be checked those toggles need to reflect that change.

http://jsfiddle.net/70fbLooL/2/

**EDIT**

Seems to be confusion as to exactly what I am trying to do. The fiddle I provided works perfectly fine. The problem is if I want to call the form from server-side and pre-populate the form the checkbox toggles will not show that they are checked because it's based on the `clicked` function. I need it to be based on if the checkbox equal true or checked. That way if the value equals true from the server-side call it will toggle those classes and look like it's checked.

Comment: Sort of like this. $(".companyCheckBox").is(":checked", function(){});

Comment: you should add problem in your fiddle.

Comment: how can you have two elements having same `ids` your both checkbox have same id.

Comment: well that was just to test the jquery. They will not have the same ids.

Comment: @Lynx is this what are you trying to do:http://jsfiddle.net/70fbLooL/6/

Comment: Not I edited my question to explain a little further. Thanks

Comment: @Lynx so you want to trigger a click on page load? How do you populate your items?

Comment: Well lets say the form can be preloaded with data via PHP from a database. If they have the first_name selected already then it should be selected. The checkbox is hidden by CSS and the toggles are what is showing in place of the checkbox. So, if they have selected the first_name it should show as checked by the checkbox and that would mean those toggles need to be shown as selected also.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code that works for you:

```
$(".companyCheckBox").click(function () {
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
       $(this).find(".fa-check").toggle();
       $(this).toggleClass("companyLabelBackground");
    }
});
```

That's it.

Comment: No, that's not what I am needing. The jQuery code in the fiddle works. I am just needing it changed up from looking at the label to looking if the checkbox is checked. Thanks

Comment: No that doesn't work. Even if it did that wouldn't solve my issue. If data is pre-loaded to the form the checkboxes and the classes would need to be toggled to reflect that they are checked.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(".companyCheckBox").click(function () {
     var obj = $(this).prev('.companyLabel');
     if($(this).is(':checked')){
         $(obj).find(".fa-check").toggle();
         $(obj).toggleClass("companyLabelBackground");
     }
});
```

Comment: Kind of the same issue with the other answer. If data is pre-loaded to the checkbox it will not toggle the classes since its using a click function.

Comment: Didn't seem to work. If I put the checked abbr on the checkbox it does not toggle the classes